# How do you deal with user settings and pure pipes in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-pipe

So, we have a requirement where we need to format certain numbers according to the user's preferences. These preferences should supersede Intl rules, so that users can format numbers with different thousand and decimal separators regardless of their original language.

We developed our own pure pipe that works like this:

```
<span>{{ value | formatValue:thousandSeparator:decimalSeparator}} </span>
```

Where `thousandSeparator` and `decimalSeparator` are obtained through `LocalStorage`.

The problem with this approach is that we need to repeat the "get and observe local storage values" code everywhere. We could use a service to isolate that logic, but we still need to pass the values everywhere in the code.

I was wondering if there was a way to write this pipe in a way that it can react to the LocalStorage api without explicitly passing these settings as arguments to the pipe, while also keeping it pure(so it doesn't re-render unless necessary)

I'm also open to solutions that are not pipes; we use pipes because we thought it'd be the best solution for this(we need to format big tables with these settings so pure pipes sound like the best solution), but if there are other ways I'm all ears.

Comment: Why not use a service in combination with your pipe?